# Want to create logs for each bundle separately in servicemix

Tags: logging, apache-servicemix

I have 3 bundles(Maven Modules) in my Maven project, servicemix creates log with name karaf.log under data\log folder by default. Now I want to create a log file for each bundle separately i.e.

> Maven module 1 = data\log\module1\karaf.log
>
> Maven module 2 = data\log\module2\karaf.log
>
> Maven module 3 = data\log\module3\karaf.log

What should I do to achieve this. Share the necessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Karaf Sift appender.

More information can be found here: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/users-guide/log.html

The sift appender is not enabled by default. This appender allows you to have one log file per deployed bundle.

```
# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name
log4j.appender.sift.default=karaf
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=${karaf.data}/log/$\\{bundle.name\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

To enable sifr appender you can modify your org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg as shown here:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, sift
```